# openpyxl not updating in the loop

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwt

In my loop I am trying to get a different value for the ws.cell(2,5) on each iteration, but the value that I get is always the same. Normally I should get 1188 different values through the iterations.

I wonder if ".to_excel" function does indeed save the dataframes to the excel columns here or not.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn = r'C:\\Users\\MuellerM\\CSV\\book2.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')

wb=load_workbook(fn, data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
num_rolls = 0

  
dfff = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0, engine='openpyxl')
kathode_cols = pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name='Katodes',header=0, engine='openpyxl')
anode_cols = pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name='Anodes',header=0, engine='openpyxl')
Lam_cols = pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name='Lambs',header=0, engine='openpyxl')

for i in range(len(kathode_cols.columns)):
    dfff.loc[:, 'Katode'] = kathode_cols.loc[:, kathode_cols.columns[i]]
    (dfff.loc[:, 'Katode']).to_excel(writer, startcol=0,startrow=1, header=None, index=False)
    for j in range(len(anode_cols.columns)):
        dfff.loc[:, 'Anode'] = anode_cols.loc[:, anode_cols.columns[j]]
        (dfff.loc[:, 'Anode']).to_excel(writer, startcol=1,startrow=1, header=None, index=False)
        for k in range(len(Lam_cols.columns)):
            dfff.loc[:, 'Lamb'] = Lam_cols.loc[:, Lam_cols.columns[k]]
            (dfff.loc[:, 'Lamb']).to_excel(writer, startcol=2,startrow=1, header=None, index=False)
            print(ws.cell(2,5).value)
            num_rolls+=1
```